# Display Value in Django template every time for loop runs

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to print values in my template every time for loop runs.

My code:

```
for a in result:
   b = []
   for i in test:
       b.append(x[i])

   return render(request, 'test.html', {'b': b}
```

I know above code is wrong but how can I print or send data to django template every time loop runs. I want to send them to seperate table every time for loop runs. I can't append all of them to same list and print all at the same time.

Comment: You can loop in templates `{% for a in result %}`? Also what exactly do you want to do? Please add expected output.

Comment: No,  actually lot of computation is done after that loop which won't be possible in template

Comment: I repeat what is the expected output?... You can simply perform computation in the view and pass a suitable data structure in the context.

Comment: But I want to display every loop data in different table, i.e. every time a for loop runs a new table will be created and will display the data

Answer (score 0):

The question seems unclear, please provide more details and **the expected output**.
However, if I'm not mistaken, you said:

> "display every loop data in different table ... every time a for loop runs a new table will be created"

why not build a table inside your `for` loop, something like:

```html
{% for entry in b %}
<table>
   <tr>
       <your_data_structure_here>
   </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what you are doing in template is correct but I have lot of computation after for loop and I don't think that is possible in template

Comment: You haven't provided enough information so I can't help much, but maybe you could do the computations in the `view` instead of the `template` or even change your data structure to avoid some of the computations in the first place.